# Redirect Without changing URL Apache

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to redirect one URL to another without changing the Browser URL

www.example.com/abc/(.*).xml should redirect to www.example.com/abc/xyz/index.htm?file=$1

But the Browser should display www.example.com/abc/(.*).xml

Comment: Im pretty sure thats impossible. Thats like trying to tell a taxi driver you want to go to 21 fake street but you actually want to go to 38 real street. The address is supposed to redirect you to the address specified. I guess you could have a look at URL masking http://blog.clickmeter.com/link-cloaking-vs-url-masking/ If i understand your question a little better.

Comment: @KyleT this is not impossible at all... There are a couple of ways to do it

Comment: @arco444 Yeah i just figured out what the OP was asking. I suggested URL masking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /abc/(.*)\.xml$ /abc/xyz/index.htm?file=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled and put this either in your `VirtualHost` config, or in a `.htaccess` file in your `DocumentRoot`

Comment: @acro444 Thanks for the quick reply. I just added P flag instead of L and it worked perfectly. 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /abc/(.*)\.xml$ /abc/xyz/index.htm?file=$1 [P]

Comment: It definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

As Constantine posted on the accepted solution, the [P] flag is dangerous as it converts the server as a proxy.

See [this]: https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever?noredirect=1&lq=1

```
P = Proxy. Forces the rule to be handled by mod_proxy. Transparently provide content from other servers, because your web-server fetches it and re-serves it. This is a dangerous flag, as a poorly written one will turn your web-server into an open-proxy and That is Bad.
```